# Tell what model a queryset is from in the template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am creating a list containing items from two different models and passing it to my template. Here is my view function:

```
def newsfeed(request):
    Text = Post.objects.all().order_by('-Timestamp')
    Images = ImagePost.objects.all().order_by('-Timestamp')
    Posts = []

    while True:
        if Text[0].Timestamp >= Images[0].Timestamp:
            Posts.append(Post.objects.get(id=Text[0].id))
            Text = Text.exclude(id=Text[0].id)
        else:
            Posts.append(ImagePost.objects.get(id=Images[0].id))
            Images = Images.exclude(id=Images[0].id)
        if len(Text) == 0:
            for i in Images:
                Posts.append(i)
            break
        elif len(Images) == 0:
            for i in Text:
                Posts.append(i)
            break
    print(Posts[:6])

    return render(request, 'campaign/newsfeed.html', {
        "posts": Posts,
    })
```

I need a way to find out which model each item in the list was from in the template so that I know how to render the item. Is there a way to tell without sending further data to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give both models (or their common super class) a method:

```
def model_name(self): 
    return self.__class__.__name__
```

And in the template, you can check:

```
{% for p in posts %}
  {% if p.model_name == 'ImagePost'%}
    # ...
  {% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

If these are models from third-party packages, you can always just set attributes in the view:

```
for i in Images:
    i.model_name = 'ImagePost'
    Posts.append(i)
```